# php, как установить и запустить на Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php

Не могу установить и настроить сервер для php, до этого учил django. Там все просто установил Python , запустил venvironment и работаешь спокойно. Может кто подскажет как ПОЭТАПНО установить и настроить Apache , php И все что нужно будет??

Comment: Инструкций в интернете даже больше чем про питон, что у вас не получается?

Comment: Устанавливал все как на сайте https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/ на sudo systemctl restart apache2.service получаю ошибку  sudo: unable to resolve host morilon
. Не понимаю что дальше делать?

Comment: @Dorian `unable to resolve host morilon` означает, что имя хоста `morilon` не получается преобразовать в ip-адрес. Вам либо нужна запись в файле `/etc/hosts` для этого имени, либо в вашем DNS сервере (если знаете где это и как правильно добавлять в него записи).

Comment: Добавил, ошибки теперь нет. Как мне запустить Apache сервер? Я создал .php файл как мне запустить его? Если просто нажимаю на него мышкой - открывается FireFox и предлагает этот же файл сохранить.